# Using r.reclass.area.lesser in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, reclassify

I want to reclass small areas in QGIS 2.18, but it seems to fail calling the algorithm in GRASS GIS. The interesting lines from the Log of the tool:

```
...
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.region n=5478291.27701 s=5058891.27701 e=2350688.13497 w=1982088.13497 res=100.0


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.reclass.area input="tmp1521273631216" mode=lesser value="60" output="outpute5c09076262546938021350e8d68b972"
--overwrite  Der Befehl """" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder  konnte nicht gefunden werden.

...
```

(It says that command """" is written wrong or not available)

Any ideas to fix that or to use another tool in QGIS for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using GDAL the tools.
The `gdal_sieve.py` works well. A bit confusing it is called "Sieben" in German...

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it on my Fedora Linux machine, the name is `r.reclass.area` (and it provides both "lesser" and "greater" options.

Test run:

```
QGIS version: 3.28.15-Firenze
Qt version: 5.15.11
Python version: 3.11.7
GDAL version: 3.6.4
GEOS version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.5.6 (git-version: Release)
Algorithm started at: 2024-03-10T17:16:42
Algorithm 'r.reclass.area' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-c' : False, '-d' : False, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'input' : '/home/mneteler/data/latlong_wgs84_asia_lst_daily_2017_asia_daily_avg_20170101_raster.tif', 'method' : 0, 'mode' : 0, 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'value' : 1 }

g.proj -c wkt="/tmp/processing_XRgRdj/390d8c868d6d46b0b0259ffc29d854b2/crs.prj"
r.in.gdal input="/home/mneteler/data/latlong_wgs84_asia_lst_daily_2017_asia_daily_avg_20170101_raster.tif" band=1 output="rast_65eddceadc2c32" --overwrite -o
g.region n=53.75 s=15.75 e=135.25 w=73.25 res=0.008333333333333333
r.reclass.area input=rast_65eddceadc2c32 value=1 mode="lesser" method="reclass" output=output910cc67f223d40fdb7a04f6d9b31ce34 --overwrite
g.region raster=output910cc67f223d40fdb7a04f6d9b31ce34
r.out.gdal -t -m input="output910cc67f223d40fdb7a04f6d9b31ce34" output="/tmp/processing_XRgRdj/84fcac6b47a74cfc8c5067980ea6d7d4/output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
...
```

Since QGIS 2.18 is pretty old (from 2019!), please consider to update to QGIS 3.x.